# Microsoft.NETCore.APP >= 1.01 could not be resolved on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise edition update 3 on my Windows 7 machine.I also installed .Net Core packages from this link:

https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows

I rebooted the machine after the installation. Now when I try and create a simple web application it throws errors related to project.json. The following are the errors thrown in Visual Studio 2015:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1001  The dependency Microsoft.NETCore.App >= 1.0.1 could not be resolved.    WebApplication14    C:\WebApplication14\src\WebApplication14\project.json   3

I haves similar errors to all the dependencies in the project.json file. I tried many options mentioned online but it did not resolve the issue. I also tried uninstalling and installing .Net core and no luck. Could you let me know how I could fix this issue.

Comment: Does this machine use some special proxy settings that prevent NuGet.org access?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. I tried uninstalling and installing .Net core and it did not work. The problem was with the NuGet Cache. The cache is stored in different location and we need to clear it which will help the packages to be restored. Follow these steps:

Go to the directory where nuget.exe has been installed and run these commands:

1) nuget locals all -list
2) nuget locals all -clear

When you run the second command you will get a warning we can just ignore that.After executing these two commands restart Visual Studio and open the project solution and it should work.